# Simple algo game

Tags: windows

Suppose I have array with zero and ones: the first n (maybe n=0) elements is 0s and others is 1s (example [0,0,1,1,1]).
But I can't see elements. I can ask to show element in some position. If it turned out that I opened two 1s (in any times) I must stop. What algorithm leads me to find last position of 0 with smallest number of opening elements?

Comment: "But I can't see elements. I can ask to show elements." That makes no sense whatsoever. Have you coded this already and it isn't working? Then post your code and add the tag.

Comment: It's like a game, I need to find algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A first guess might be to do something like binary search: try the middle element to cut the search space in half. However, it turns out this is not a great strategy given the limited number of misses available; if your first guess turns out to be a 1, the only safe strategy is to begin looking linearly from the largest known-safe position, which would be the beginning. This is a worst-case of O(n), which you also clearly get just by scanning from the front. Surely we can do better.

What if we try the elements at positions sqrt(n), 2sqrt(n), ..., n instead, iterating linearly only if we find a 1 at some point?

- We check at most sqrt(n) values before finding a 1 or exhausting all possibilities
- If we find a 1, we check at most sqrt(n) more options before finding what we need to give the answer.

Example with n = 100, split at 27.

```
check array[10]; value 0, so continue.
check array[20]; value 0, so continue.
check array[30]; value 1, so switch to linear.
check array[21]; value 0, so continue.
check array[22]; value 0, so continue.
check array[23]; value 0, so continue.
check array[24]; value 0, so continue.
check array[25]; value 0, so continue.
check array[26]; value 0, so continue.
check array[27]; value 1, so answer 26.
```

For n = 100, the worst case is the split at 99, and you check 10+9 = 19 values. An upper bound on the number of values checked is 2sqrt(n), which is O(sqrt(n)), asymptotically better than O(n) for the naïve linear-only method.

Can you do better? I am skeptical. This method achieves speedup by balancing the complexity of the fast method (skipping around by more than one) and the slow method (scanning linearly) so that they have the same number of steps in the worst case. Since the overall complexity is the sum of these two, and since everything seems pretty symmetric, I suspect that this is optimal - any other way of skipping around and then linearly scanning might do better in some cases, but must do worse in others. For instance, skipping by doubling each time - trying 2, 4, 8, ..., n - has O(n) worst-case complexity since you try log(n) values in the fast step and ~n/2 values in the slow step (if you fail when you try n, you have to check everything above ~n/2).

Answer (score -1):

Open the elements one by one using a loop and then use an if statement to check the value of the element. If the element at position j is 1, exit the loop and the last 0 is at position j-1

Comment: it's not optimal algorithm

Comment: Use binary search